# Castle Windsor: "No component for supporting the service" exception when publishing with "optimize code" enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I use the below code to register the MVC controller

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .BasedOn<IController>()

}
```

When I publish this code with "Optimize Code" disabled, it works fine. But getting the below exception, if I publish with "Optimize Code" enabled.

```
No component for supporting the service Test.TestController was found
```

on the line marked below:

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    if (controllerType == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
    }

    return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType); //exception raised HERE
}
```

Comment: How looks your controller like?

Comment: public class TestController : Controller
{
  ....
}